# How to extract a variable length substring using ksh

Tags: shell, substring, ksh

I need to extract a variable length sub string using Korn shell on Linux.

Sample String: `"SID_LIST_ORADBPOC1LSN ="`

Need to extract substring: `"ORADBPOC1LSN"`

Note: The sample substring is of variable length.

Thanks in advance.

FR

Comment: assuming that you're looking to delete the `SID_LIST` (prefix) and the trailing `" ="`, you can use parameter substitution, i.e. `str="SID_LIST_ORADBPOC1LSN ="; varFix="${str#SID_LIST_}"; varFix=${varFix% =}; echo "$varFix"`. Output is : `ORADBPOC1LSN` . Good luck.

Comment: you should probably provide several examples of before/after values, or will all input values have the same format of `(string) + '_' + (string) + '_' + (string) + (space) + '='`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pure bash's parameter expansion capability.

```
var="SID_LIST_ORADBPOC1LSN ="  ##Creating shell variable here.
temp1="${var##*_}"             ##Removing everything till _ ## for longest match here.
echo "${temp1/ =/}"            ##Substituting space = with null here.
ORADBPOC1LSN
```

I am printing value of temp1's parameter expansion, you could save this into variable too as per your need.

---

---

OR if you want to do it in a single `awk` or so then try:

```
echo "$var" | awk -F'_| ' '{print $3}'
```